# c# struct in function not assignable

Tags: c#, struct

I defined a `struct` like this

```
    public enum LineType
    {
        Red,//angle<th,L>th
        Green,//L<th
        Blue,//angle>th,L>th
        none
    }

    public struct LineData
    {
        public double angle;
        public double length;
        public LineType lineType;
        public int number;
    }
```

In another class called `DataTableTools`, I defined a `function`

```
class DataTableTools
{
    public enum LineType
    {
        Red,//angle<th,L>th
        Green,//L<th
        Blue,//angle>th,L>th
        none
    }

    public struct LineData
    {
        public double angle;
        public double length;
        public LineType lineType;
        public int number;
    }

    public bool InsertData(LineData lineData)
    {
        ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

However, when I called `function` in main dialog:

```
DataTableTools dtTools=new DataTableTools();
bool b=dtTools.InsertData(lineData);
```

`An error occurred: Argument type '...MainDialog.LineData' is not assignable to parameter type 'DataTableTools.LineData'.
I really confused about it. Why LineData type was different in different class?`

Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you provide full sample code? Currently it is not clear if you declare `LineType` and `LineData` twice, it is not clear what the value of variable `lineData` is.

Comment: Seems you defined two `LineData` class/struct, one is from your above code, another is from `MainDialog`.

Comment: Try making class DataTableTools public.  It doesn't help having the properties and methods public when the class is not public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your LineData struct inside DataTableTools class is call [`Nested Type`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx). It's often use to implicit the idea `this nested struct/class is only use for this class`, So the class **DataTableTools** will recognize the parameter struct **LineData** in InsertData() as DataTableTools.LineData. That is clearly different from MainDialog.LineData that you defined in your **MainDialog** class.

For your case, you should use

```
DataTableTools dtTools=new DataTableTools();
DataTableTools.LineData  lineData = new DataTableTools.LineData ();
//Do something with lineData 
bool b=dtTools.InsertData(lineData);
```

Second solution could be [c-sharp-convert-struct-to-another-struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798891/c-sharp-convert-struct-to-another-struct) , from struct `MainDialog.LineData` to `DataTableTools.LineData`

Comment: Based on your experience, what is the best way if I have to define same struct in different classes? The method you provided seems a bit of complex. Thanks.

Comment: If you find the 2nd solution complex, then you could make a constructor for **DataTableTools.LineData**, then call `DataTableTools.LineData  newLineData = new DataTableTools.LineData (lineData.angle, lineData.length, lineData.lineType, lineData.number);`, with **lineData** is instance of that struct from class **MainDialog**

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have accidentally re-declared your enum and struct. Did you mean to define your class something more like this:

```
class DataTableTools
{
    public LineType LineType { get; set; }
    public LineData LineData { get; set; }

    public bool InsertData(LineData lineData)
    {
        this.LineData.angle = lineData.angle
        ...
        return true;
    }
}
```

That would allow you to do something like this:

```
DataTableTools dtTools=new DataTableTools();
bool b=dtTools.InsertData(lineData);
```